# Trying to abstract library Objective-C function into protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to abstract an Objective-C function from the Firebase Firestore library into a protocol so I can inject my own version of the library for tests.

There is the following Objective-C function which I can't seem to abstract properly:

```
- (FIRCollectionReference *)collectionWithPath:(NSString *)collectionPath
NS_SWIFT_NAME(collection(_:));
```

I have tried to abstract it like:

```
func collection(withPath collectionPath: String) -> CollectionReferenceProtocol
```

But when I try to extend `Firestore` with my protocol, it says it doesn't conform to the protocol. What's the correct way to define that Objective-C function in Swift?

Comment: You’re using a label of `withPath`, but `NS_SWIFT_NAME` suggests that there should be no label (e.g. use `_` instead).

Comment: @Rob I tried that and it still says it doesn't conform

Comment: Please provide more code, like the protocol. A [mcve]